# Bash Substring multiple parameters

Tags: bash

I need to extract two parameters from each line of a svn log but I am not able to do it with grep.

My Svn log command, such as

```
svn log http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/ | grep "^r[0-9]\+ | " | cut -c2-
```

Outputs the result in this format:

```
318150 | lehors | 2002-01-28 20:48:11 +0100 (Mon, 28 Jan 2002) | 2 lines
318149 | elena | 2002-01-28 20:46:33 +0100 (Mon, 28 Jan 2002) | 12 lines
318148 | lehors | 2002-01-28 20:33:36 +0100 (Mon, 28 Jan 2002) | 2 lines
318147 | lehors | 2002-01-28 20:22:51 +0100 (Mon, 28 Jan 2002) | 2 lines
```

How can I grep the release number (first parameter) and the date in this format?

```
318150 2002-01-28
318149 2002-01-28
318148 2002-01-28
318147 2002-01-28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a more robust `Awk` for this to pattern-match/extract from individual columns.

```
.. | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{split($3,temp, " "); print $1,temp[1]}'
318150  2002-01-28
318149  2002-01-28
318148  2002-01-28
318147  2002-01-28
```

The `.. |` part represents the command to be included that produces the required output which is pipe-lined to `Awk`

The logic is pretty straight-forward, split input lines with de-limiter as `|` which is done by `FS="|"`. Now `$1` represents the first field you want, and for the second part, split the part `$3` and use the `split()` function to split on delimiter, a white-space character and store it in array `temp`, so that it can be accessed as `temp[1]`, the other space fields are present in the array from the next index on wards.

So ideally I guess it should be,

```
svn log http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/ | \
   awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{split($3,temp, " "); print $1,temp[2]}'
```

---

Alternatively you could use `GNU grep` with its `-E` extended regular expression capabilities, but it is just not good enough to show the matching entries on same line like,

```
grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}' file
```

(and)

```
grep -oE '^[[:digit:]]{6}' file
```

but not together as I have used the `-o` flag to print the match only part.

Comment: Just realized that this will print the time and OP wants the date, so changing temp[2] by temp[1] will do it :)

Answer (score 1):

As your file is separated by a single space and you want to have the first and 5th columns, this is another solution by using `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,5 < svn_log_output_file
```

(or piping `cut -d' ' -f1,5` to your command)

Comment: Also, you could do process substitution as,  `cut -d' ' -f1,5 < <(svn log http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/)`

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach with multiple delimiters-

```
awk -F '[| ]' '{print $1, $7}' file
```

Where `file` contains the output you showed in your question.

Output-

```
318150 2002-01-28
318149 2002-01-28
318148 2002-01-28
318147 2002-01-28
```

Of course, you don't need to store in an intermediate file. You can do-

```
svn log http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/ \
| grep "^r[0-9]\+ | " | cut -c2- | \
awk -F '[| ]' '{print $1, $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$5}' file

318150 2002-01-28
318149 2002-01-28
318148 2002-01-28
318147 2002-01-28
```